# Questing addons in WOW

Tags: world-of-warcraft, mods

I'm considering using an quest-helper-addon to make my life easier. I saw that **QuestHelper** is rated number 1 by many websites. However one of my friends swears by **Carbonite Quest**.
Which one of these addons has the most features, and which one is N00b(me) Friendly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, heres the Heads-Up. I'm a WoTLK player (Patch 3.3.5a), and I swear by Carbonite too.

Quest helper is mostly just a tiny little arrow pointing you in the direction that your quest target is in, but doesn't take into account that there may be multiple zones where you can finish your quest.

Carbonite , on the other hand, Tracks your quests on a interactive minimap, Zones out all the locations in color , points you in the right direction, and even warns you when enemy players are abound. It also contains a list of quests that needs to be completed in a handy little box.

downside is, Playing the game without either addons named above is the best way to learn and to use your quest log and Map.

so this is really a question of "What is your flavour?"

Comment: The downside of these addons are that they aren't memory friendly. Carbonite uses 11mb of memory, while QuestHelper uses a whopping 23Mb by me. So I disabled them both. All I use is Recount, Xperl, Bartender, Gearscore, Quartz3, Omen3, OmniCC, TitanPanel and when I'm a clothie, FortXorcist

Comment: memory as in RAM? Cause i got 4gb so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: then IMO , use carbonite.  I got a weak pc running with 1.5gb.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old question, but these days [Questie](https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/questie) seems to be where it's at.